# How do I deploy an application that has separate front end (angular) and back end (spring boot) on a live server with cPanel?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, vue.js, cpanel

Sorry if it's kind of a silly question, but I only have experience in working with angular and spring boot locally on localhost so I'm not sure about the whole deployment on a live server process.

I currently purchased a domain and the server has a cPanel interface.

What do I need to do in order for my app to run as it runs on localhost?

Comment: can you comment on the environment details you purchase so I could update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run two environments.
One is to run jar files[backend].
second is to run angular [frontend].

There are many options you can suffice above two conditions.
The simplest way is to buy a virtual machine with a Linux server.